# how to delete key from list in redis matching a pattern?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, redis

Using the ruby redis client

I have a key that contains a list of values they follow the pattern of

```
campaign_id|telephone|query_id
```

there are thousands of these in a individual list what i want to do is delete all the ones that have for example the query_id of 4 from that redis list. Can you do this through some sort of pattern matching? Please could someone give me an example as i've been reading through other questions and am a bit lost

Comment: `list.reject { |e| e =~ /|#{query_id}$/ }`

Comment: I mean actually delete them from redis not reject them from whats returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have one of two options: a) do it your (RoR) application or b) do it in Redis.

I'm not a RoR expert so I can't advise on the how, but note that taking the a) path you'll basically be moving the entire list to your application and there do the filtering. The bigger your list is, the more time it will take it to cross the network.

Option b) means that you'll be filtering the list right in Redis - this can be done simply and efficiently when you use Lua. Example:

```
$ cat dellistbyqueryid.lua
-- removes a range of list elements that confirm to a given
-- query_id. Elements are stored as: 'campaign_id|telephone|query_id'
-- KEYS[1] - a list
-- ARGV[1] - a query_id
-- return: number of elements removed

local l = tonumber(redis.call('LLEN', KEYS[1]))
local n = 0

while l > 0 do
  local curr = redis.call('LINDEX', KEYS[1], -1)
  local id = curr:match( '.*|.*|(.*)' )
  if id == ARGV[1] then
    redis.call('RPOP', KEYS[1])
    n = n + 1
  else
    redis.call('RPOPLPUSH', KEYS[1], KEYS[1])
  end
  l = l - 1
end

return n
```

Output:

```
$ redis-cli LPUSH list "foo|bar|1" "baz|qaz|2" "lua|redis|1"
(integer) 3
$ redis-cli --eval dellistbyqueryid.lua list , 1
(integer) 2
$ redis-cli LRANGE list 0 -1
1) "baz|qaz|2"
```

Comment: But where is actual deleting part? I guess author asked about deleting value from list not filtering output. And regarding case a) this case basically means to filter all list in RoR and then swap existing list with filtered one? Because LREM doesnt supprot removing by regexp nor removing by index.

Comment: @RuslanN You're actually very very very correct. Editing immediately.